# Django store user image in model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a field in a model, that should store an image for a registered user.
This image should be renamed and stored in a separate user directory like `media/users/10/photo.jpeg`.

I've searched a lot, but still can't find how to do it cleanly and correctly. It seems to me that many sites require the same functionality and this should be in django docs, but it is not.

Comment: You are creating a directory for every user id? Why not `media/users/10.jpeg`? Just asking :D

Comment: Because there could be other user-related content to store :)

Comment: Oh I see! I think I've faced a similar problem let me see if I can help

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You want to use the "upload_to" option on an `ImageField`

```
#models.py
import os

def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('photos', str(instance.id), filename)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    profile_image = ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
```

This is code directly from a project of mine. The uploaded image goes to `/MEDIA_ROOT/photos/<user_id>/filename`

For what you want, just change the 'photos' string to 'users' in `def get_image_path`

Here is the small bit about it in the docs, under [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#filefield) details

Comment: Cool, this actually does save file to the correct location, but when I use in template ``{{ user.profile_image }}`` it for some reason gives ``/users/users/40/photo.png`` instead of ``/media/users/40/photo.png``

Comment: models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
should be models.OneToOneField(User)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to look into django-photologue. Its a django app with all image managment, uploading and storing already done!

More about at: http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make a model that has a foreign key to the User model, where you can have an [image field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) for the User. I would not recommend modifying the User model itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question is not about the model, it's about how to store images.

Comment: You can create a dynamic upload path for any FileField or Image field. Just add a function to your model that returns the path for upload_to. You can find an example in the Django docs at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#filefield

Comment: @ShamsulArefinSajib This answer is 7 years old. The updated link is: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#imagefield