# Django upload file per user relationship error

Tags: django, django-models, django-file-upload

I'm making an app, which requires users to upload some files. I want to store all files in a username folder (and possibly, later move it outside the project folder, but that's other thing)

First I'm doing some tests, I took this example [S.O: Need a minimal django file upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example).

It worked just like that, so I moved to next step.

I checked this questions:

[Django FileField with upload_to determined at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190697/django-filefield-with-upload-to-determined-at-runtime)

[Dynamic File Path in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135556/dynamic-file-path-in-django)

[Django store user image in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189800/django-store-user-image-in-model?rq=1)

My current models.py:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import os

def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('docs', instance.owner.username, filename)

class Document(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

My views.py

```
@login_required
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myapp.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'myapp/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

All accepted answers, lead to the same solution. But I'm getting an error with instance.owner:

```
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist
DoesNotExist
raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist
```

Using werkzeug debbuger:

```
>>> instance
<Document: Document object>
>>> instance.owner
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<debugger>", line 1, in <module>
instance.owner
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 343,     in    __get__
raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist
DoesNotExist
```

What am I missing?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to save a `Document` object as :

```
newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
newdoc.save()
```

But you haven't set `owner` for it, you in `get_upload_path` method `instance.owner` is not defined/set and `instance.owner.username` will fail.

Either you change your save as:

```
newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
newdoc.owner = request.user #set owner
newdoc.save()
```

I'm not sure, what is your `DocumentForm` is. But if it also has `owner` field then you can directly save it instead of creating `newdoc` separately as:

```
...
if form.is_valid():
    newdoc = form.save()
...
```

Comment: oh god, such a silly error and I didn't see it. It seems to work now. Thank you very much.