# Django - using instance.id while uploading image

Tags: python, mysql, django

I was referring to this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rr1-UTFCuH4&t=8s&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzQFqfCur9CJ4QnKQTVXUsRy&index=28), to understand how to upload image using ImageField. He has explained how to use the `instance.id` while saving the image. I tried it, but `instance.id` is returning `None`. Whereas for him it worked perfectly. The following is the code:

```
#models.py
import os

def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(str(instance.id), filename)

class AdProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
```

Whenever the file is saved, its saving as `None/filename`.

Even this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189800/django-store-user-image-in-model) informs the same. I am using Django 10.5 and MySQL database.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Tell how you upload the file and when `save()` called ?

Comment: I uploaded the file using admin panel. It dint write any additional `save()` method.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem you need to tell the Admin `save()` to use the `get_image_path` I'm writing  the answer now..

Comment: Okay @RajaSimon

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Django admin somehow called the get_image_path function without saving the model to database so id is None. We can override django model using save method and make sure image is saved and get_image_path get the instance with id

```
class AdProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)

    # Model Save override 
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.id is None:
            saved_image = self.profile_image
            self.profile_image = None
            super(AdProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            self.profile_image = saved_image
            if 'force_insert' in kwargs:
                kwargs.pop('force_insert')

        super(AdProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You are awesome. It worked perfectly as expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: is there any way to do the same, while using `views.py`?

Comment: I am getting the following error: `(1062, "Duplicate entry '8' for key 'PRIMARY'")`. I was using DRF to save the image.

Comment: Perfect!
I just had to check if 'force_insert' exists in kwargs:
            if 'force_insert' in kwargs:
                kwargs.pop('force_insert')
to avoid an error, Django 2.1.2, Python 3.6

Comment: @RedPelle Thanks for the suggestion. Can you edit the answer so that I can accept your edit.

Comment: @RedPelle Thanks
Adding below line to the code worked both for DRF and Django admin.
`
if 'force_insert' in kwargs:
                kwargs.pop('force_insert')
`

Answer (score 2):

Using Raja Simon's answer, there is recipe to process all `FileField` in the model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    file_field = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.id is None:
            saved = []
            for f in self.__class__._meta.get_fields():
                if isinstance(f, models.FileField):
                    saved.append((f.name, getattr(self, f.name)))
                    setattr(self, f.name, None)

            super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

            for name, val in saved:
                setattr(self, name, val)
        super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Moreover, we can make file location dynamic, i.e. based not only on self.id, but also on id of foreign key or whatever. Just iterate over fields and check if path changed.

```
def upload_to(o, fn):
    if o.parent and o.parent.id:
        return parent_upload_to(o.parent, fn)

    return "my_temp_dir/{}/{}".format(o.id, fn)


class MyModel(models.Model):

    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # .... code from save() above here

        for f in [f for f in self.__class__._meta.get_fields() if isinstance(f, models.FileField)]:

            upload_to = f.upload_to

            f = getattr(self, f.name)  # f is FileField now

            if f and callable(upload_to):
                _, fn = os.path.split(f.name)
                old_name = os.path.normpath(f.name)
                new_name = os.path.normpath(upload_to(self, fn))

                if old_name != new_name:

                    old_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, old_name)
                    new_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, new_name)

                    new_dir, _ = os.path.split(new_path)
                    if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
                        print "Making  dir {}", new_dir
                        os.makedirs(new_dir)

                    print "Moving {} to {}".format(old_path, new_path)
                    try:
                        os.rename(old_path, new_path)
                        f.name = new_name

                    except WindowsError as e:
                        print "Can not move file, WindowsError: {}".format(e)

        super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```